# Jquery show hide

Tags: jquery

I have this code but i want to hide .test when window load.
This is the toggle function .I am not giving the css .I hope this is easy but i can not solve this .

```
    <script>
$('#toggleDiv').toggle(function() {
    $('.test').delay(500).animate({
        'opacity': 0,
        'right': '-100%'
    });
    $(this).delay(1000).queue(function(n) {
        $(this).html('show');
        n();
    });
}, function() {
    $('.test').delay(500).animate({
        'opacity': 1,
        'right': '0%'
    });
    $(this).delay(1000).queue(function(n) {
        $(this).html('hide');
        n();
    });
}); 
    </script>
```

html

```
<pre>
<div id="toggleDiv">hide</div>
<div class="test">This secret has been passed down from generation to generation in our family and it reveals how to win a man’s heart.</div>
</pre>
```

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you provided?

Comment: Have you used [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) before?

Comment: Make sure your code runs after the website has been constructed. To do so, either put your `<script>` tags at the bottom of your website or wrap your code in `$(function(){/* your code here */});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below.... It will help you..

**HTML:**

```
<pre>
<div id="toggleDiv">show</div>
<div class="test">This secret has been passed down from generation to generation in our family and it reveals how to win a man’s heart.</div>
</pre>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$( ".test" ).toggle();
$("#toggleDiv").click(function(){
    if($("#toggleDiv").text() =="show")
    {
        $("#toggleDiv").text("hide");
    }
    else
        $("#toggleDiv").text("show");
      $( ".test" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#toggleDiv { cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; }
```

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/2gD4Y/

*If you want to slide the div info then try like below :*

**Jquery :**

```
$(".test").hide();
$("#toggleDiv").click(function(){
    if($("#toggleDiv").text() =="show")
    {
        $("#toggleDiv").text("hide");
    }
    else
        $("#toggleDiv").text("show");
      $(".test").toggle("slide", {direction:'right'});
});
```

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/2gD4Y/1/

Comment: But I want to show it/slider either from left to right  or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.hide()` and `.show()` functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".test").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
                   $("#toggleDiv").click(function(){
                   $("#test").toggle();
                   });
               });
</script>
```